# IBM WAS Liberty Network Deployment : Is free or license is required

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-was

I know Liberty is free but want to confirm that either **IBM WAS Liberty Network Deployment profile** is free too ? and we can build clusters as well.

[This](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/lab-build-and-administer-your-own-liberty-application-cluster/) article says:

> Liberty profile Network Deployment can be downloaded as a trial if you
>   do not already have a WebSphere license.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify a few things.

WebSphere Liberty is free for **development** purposes.

For production you may use version downloaded from wasdev.net for free (without support), if the heap size doesn't excess 2GB **in the whole organization** you are working. See details about that here [What the Liberty runtime license lets you do](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-application-server-everyone/)

For any other versions like Liberty Core, Base, ND, or z/OS **you need a valid WebSphere license**.
So for example, if you already have WebSphere ND license, you can use Liberty **instead** of full WebSphere.
If you don't have any WebSphere licenses and you would like to use WebSphere Liberty in production you have to buy licenses, see here [WebSphere Application Server family](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/was-overview)

Trial versions are only for 60 days.